# клавиатура для бота вк с библиотекой vk_api

Tags: python

я хочу чтобы при написании /start бот выводил клавиатуру,

```
for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        if event.to_me:
            message = event.text.lower()
            # Получаем id пользователя
            id = event.user_id
```

вот цикл прослушки и допустим в конце

```
if message == '/start':
    #выводится клавиатура
```

подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

до цикла for нужно вставить вот эту функцию:

```
import menu

def keyboard_run(sender, message, menu):
    vk_session.method('messages.send', {
                      'chat_id': sender, 'message': message, 'random_id': get_random_id(), 'keyboard': menu.get_keyboard()})
```

Тут импортируем файл с клавиатурами, а в дальнейшем пишем функцию для её вызова.
Это что-то вроде метода обработки ответа, как и функция текстового ответа или функция вызова изображения.

Сама клавиатура:
Клавиатуры можно хранить в отдельном файле, например **menu.py**

```
group = VkKeyboard(inline=True)
group.add_button('1 вариант', color=VkKeyboardColor.SECONDARY)
group.add_button('2 вариант', color=VkKeyboardColor.SECONDARY)
group.add_button('3 вариант', color=VkKeyboardColor.SECONDARY)
```

Ну и собственно сам вызов:

```
if message == '/start'::
    keyboard_run(sender, "Текст с клавиатурой", group) # Последний параметр это та переменная, на которую мы клавиатуру привязали.
```

Comment: огромное спасибо